# Equivalent of welcome in non-greeting context

Tags: traduction

I would like to express something of the line:

> This adds a bit of confidence, which is very welcome in this
>   situation.

in the sense that 'confidence' is needed and/or appreciated in the given situation.

I wanted to translate the sentence literally, using the word `bienvenu`, but I am worried that that word might only apply in a greeting. Is that correct? How would you translate the above sentence?

Comment: Note that "bienvenu" is exactly formed as "welcome"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Bienvenu](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bienvenu)* is not restricted to greetings so would be fine here.

You might also use *[appréciable](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/appr%C3%A9ciable)*.